# react - webpack - prod release react.js external vs development local copy of react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

How can I configure webpack so that react and reactDom are used from external common location in the prod bundle but I use my local copy during development.

```
externals: {
  "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

where do I define the external location for prod? How to configure using local copy for dev?